# How to pass button value from view to controller without using form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out how can I use the button value from view to corresponding controller. I have three button which I have grouped them. Based on user selection, I want to do different functions (eg: List the task, form to add the tasks..etc). For that I want to pass the button value to the controller.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Task Lists</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Task Category</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add Task</a>
</div>
```

I am not sure if there is better way to do this than button groups. I am not familiar with javascript also. 
To make it clear, I have user information on the left side of the page which is already designed. These buttons are on the top of the right side of the page. Upon selecting the buttons, right side of the page should change/reloaded based on the selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following

```
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
      <a href="/controllor/action?value=data" class="btn btn-primary">Task Lists</a>
      <a href="/controllor/action?value=data" class="btn btn-primary">Task Category</a>
     <a href="/controllor/action?value=data" class="btn btn-primary">Add Task</a>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use links to go to the controller action you want (if I understand your question correctly).  You would use the paths/routes to the specific action you want.  It would look something like this:

```
<a href="/tasks/lists" class="btn btn-primary">Task Lists</a>
```

Or you can do it in rails direction, using the link_to method:

```
<%= link_to "Task Lists", tasks_lists_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Again, this depends what the routes you are using are.  If you want to pass parameters with the link, it gets a bit more complicated, but not much.

For more information: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Answer (score 0):

One option is triggering an ajax post request when the button is clicked and send the data to a particular controller action.

Could also just pass params through a link_to.